Convert list to table, number of rows
A small program that recalculates the number of records in the source list (array) and converts the list of data into a table.

It works if the number of rows in the table is \def\nRows{3} is specified by a number.
It doesn't work if I substitute the counted number of entries in the \def\nRows{\nstring} array.

I think the number/string format of the \nstring variable is incorrect.
What needs to be fixed for \def\nRows{\nstring} to work?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\usepackage{tikz}


%----Source data set------
\def\datalist{16.03.2022/2,  
    28.06.2022/3,     
    15.07.2022/4,}  
%---Function for counting entries in the source array--------
\newcommand\countem[2]{%
    \setsepchar{#1}%
    \readlist\countlist{#2}%
    \the\numexpr\listlen\countlist[]-1\relax}


%-------The function splits an array string into two values---------
\newcommand{\Assign}[1]{\foreach [count=\nn] \myx/\myy in \datalist
    {\ifnum\nn=#1       
        \xdef\x{\myx}  % date
        \xdef\y{\myy}  % number
        \fi     }}

\begin{document}
    \datalist    % source array
    \def\nstring{\countem{,}{\datalist}}  % counting the number of records
    \nstring   %---number of records----
    \newcounter{dateone}
    \newcounter{datetwo}
        
    \def\nRows{\nstring} %----number of rows in table: I want here \nstring
    
    \def\TAB{&}
        
\begin{table}[h] 
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{100pt}|p{80pt}|p{55pt}|} 
    \hline
    \xintiloop [1+1]

    \Assign{\xintiloopindex}
    \x \TAB \y \TAB Text  \\ \hline
    
    \ifnum\nRows>\xintiloopindex\space % iterating over array
    \repeat
    
    & &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}
\end{document}


I think, it's time to learn How to mark code blocks using markdown.

@cabohah - I'm trying, but apparently not very well)

If a question has been edited, you can always compare the revisions to learn more about the changes. Also click to the different visualizations, e.g., "Side-by-side Markdown" in the revision view.

You might take a look at pgfplotstable.  You have to specify the columns, but the numbers of rows is computed internally (as they are filled).

The macro \readlist is not expandable.  So including \countem as part of a \def will not expand.  Instead, execute \countem prior to the assignment, and then you can assign with
\edef\nstring{\the\numexpr\listlen\countlist[]-1\relax}

In this way, \nstring will be expanded (or expandable, if you use a \def rather than \edef.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\usepackage{tikz}


%----Source data set------
\def\datalist{16.03.2022/2,  
    28.06.2022/3,     
    15.07.2022/4,}  
%---Function for counting entries in the source array--------
\newcommand\countem[2]{%
    \setsepchar{#1}%
    \readlist\countlist{#2}%
%    \the\numexpr\listlen\countlist[]-1\relax
}


%-------The function splits an array string into two values---------
\newcommand{\Assign}[1]{\foreach [count=\nn] \myx/\myy in \datalist
    {\ifnum\nn=#1       
        \xdef\x{\myx}  % date
        \xdef\y{\myy}  % number
        \fi     }}

\begin{document}
    \datalist    % source array
    \countem{,}{\datalist}  % counting the number of records
    \edef\nstring{\the\numexpr\listlen\countlist[]-1\relax}  % counting the number of records
    \nstring   %---number of records----
    \newcounter{dateone}
    \newcounter{datetwo}
        
    \def\nRows{\nstring} %----number of rows in table: I want here \nstring
    
    \def\TAB{&}
        
\begin{table}[h] 
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{100pt}|p{80pt}|p{55pt}|} 
    \hline
    \xintiloop [1+1]

    \Assign{\xintiloopindex}
    \x \TAB \y \TAB Text  \\ \hline
    
    \ifnum\nRows>\xintiloopindex\space % iterating over array
    \repeat
    
    & &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}
\end{document}

Alternately, you can define \nstring within \countem itself, using the same provisos I gave earlier:
\newcommand\countem[2]{%
    \setsepchar{#1}%
    \readlist\countlist{#2}%
    \edef\nstring{\the\numexpr\listlen\countlist[]-1\relax}
}



Steven B. Segletes - I still have a hard time understanding the topic of macro expansion and thank you for your help, everything works

Why you load package tikz? I give my solution using LaTeX3, wish i fully understand your request.
\documentclass{article}

%----Source data set------
\def\datalist{%
  16.03.2022/2,%  
  28.06.2022/3,%     
  15.07.2022/4,%
}  

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \__data_to_table:nnn #1#2#3 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}{#3}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {#2}{##1}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { & }\\
  } 
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__data_to_table:nnn { nnx }
\NewDocumentCommand{\datatotable}{O{,}O{/}m}{
  \__data_to_table:nnx {#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}        
\begin{table}[h] 
  \caption{test}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{100pt}|p{80pt}|p{55pt}|} 
    \hline
    \datatotable{\datalist}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

then it will give you:

